# Vue 3: prop with Validator => TypeScript Error Claiming Other prop Does not Exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, validation, vuejs3

In Vue (v3) adding a prop with a `validator` causes a TypeScript error claiming that another property does not exist. I have created a component illustrating the problem:

This works:

```
<template>
  <div>{{myComputed}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    someProp: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      myComputed: computed(() => ('ABC_' + props.someProp + '_XYZ'))
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Now we add `otherProp` with a `validator`:

```
<template>
  <div>{{myComputed}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: {
    someProp: String,
    otherProp: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      validator: (v) => (true) // <- Problem occurs when
                               //    adding this line
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      myComputed: computed(() => ('ABC_' + props.someProp + '_XYZ'))
      // Complains that `props.someProp` --^
      // is not defined here
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

We get an error with this message:

```
ERROR in src/components/MyComponent.vue:21:50
TS2339: Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{ [x: number]: string; } & { length?: number | undefined; toString?: string | undefined; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; join?: string | undefined; ... 17 more ...; flat?: unknown[] | undefined; }> | Readonly<...>>>'.
    19 |   setup(props) {
    20 |     return {
  > 21 |       myComputed: computed(() => ('ABC_' + props.someProp + '_XYZ'))
       |                                                  ^^^^^^^^
    22 |       // Complains that `props.someProp` --^
    23 |       // is not defined here
    24 |     };
```

Using the `computed` object instead of the `computed` function in `setup` produces a similar result (then complaining that `this.someProp` does not exist, even though it does at runtime).

Why does this error occur? How could we have predicted this behaviour? Is `validator` still supported?

Current workaround: I dropped `validator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the type to the `validator` parameter :

```
otherProp: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  validator: (v:string) => (true)
                // ^-----------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work for you or it is not enouth, it might help to wrap your props in a defineProps like that:

```
  props: defineProps({
    otherProp: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      validator: (v) => (true)
    }
  }),
```